# .NET BindingSource Filter syntax reference

Tags: c#, .net, filter, bindingsource

You can use the Filter property of a BindingSource to do SQL like filtering.
For example:

```
bindingSource.Filter= "Activated = 1"
```

**Is there something like documentation on the exact syntax of this?**

I would like to check if a field is not DBNull, so i tried "Field != NULL" but it gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax is generally the same as what would you would use in a SQL Where clause, without the "Where", so in this case, it would be

```
  bindingSource.Filter = "Field <> NULL";
```

If you look at msdn docs for BindingSource.Filter you will see this:

"To form a filter value, specify the name of a column followed by an operator and a value to filter on. The accepted filter syntax depends on the underlying data source. If the underlying data source is a DataSet, DataTable, or DataView, you can specify Boolean expressions ***using the syntax documented for the [DataColumn..::.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) property.***"

Follow that link to see all the detailed rules

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [this msdn article](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx). The described syntax should be valid for your `BindingSource`, too.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was

```
bindingSource.Filter = "columnName Is Null";
```

or conversely

```
bindingSource.Filter = "columnName Is Not Null";
```